# how to retrieve a sql datetime object with a php $row?

Tags: php, sql-server, datetime

For instance:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM db";
$query = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql);

while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($query)){
    echo "$row[date_column]";
}
```

will crash

Most of the answers I've found are assuming you want to order your query by a datetime, but I just want to turn the datetime object into a string after I have all the rows.

I don't really understand how to use the php date() function,
I've tried:

```
echo date("m/d/Y",$row[date_column]); //prints nothing
```

Comment: that's more mssql question rather than php

Answer (score 4):

```
$string=$row["date_column"]->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')
```

Answer (score 1):

```
while($row=sqlsrv_fetch_array($rs,SQLSRV_FETCH_NUMERIC))
{
    $logdate=date_format($row[4],"Y-m-d H:i:s");
}
```

here, $row[4] contains the date object. 
This would surely help.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, if "date_column" is the column name, it should be in quotes, like this:

```
echo $row["date_column"];
```

Secondly, PHP has a built-in function to turn MYSQL datetime into a unix timestamp, which PHP date() can use. Try this:

```
echo date("m/d/Y", strtotime($row["date_column"]));
```

Cheers!

Comment: Question is asking about MSSQL, not MySQL, but I don't see why this method would not work for both.

Comment: Whoops, your right! But yes, it should if MSSQL stores datetime the same.

Comment: Hi, thanks for you answer, however, what I am getting from        `echo date("m/d/Y", strtotime($row["date_column"]);`                        is the date: 12/31/1969 for every entry.  Also, that is not the correct date for any of the entries.

Comment: You will get that date when PHP date() is given a bad input value. So I can help you more, can I have a sample of what "echo $row["date_column"];" produces?

Comment: it returns a datetime object (for the Data Type in sql) and the format is  `yyyy-mm-dd hh:nn:ss.xxx`  where n = minutes and x = milliseconds I think.

Comment: That's strange. It works when I try it on my server, with the format you provided. The code I am trying is:
    "$time = "2001-01-13 10:45:55.123";
    echo date("m/d/Y", strtotime($time));"
Which produces: "01/13/2001". What do you get when you just try "echo strtotime($row["date_column"]);"?