# SQL Server -> PHP Date

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, date, datatables

I'm having trouble with SQL Server date coming to my php file.
I've researched but none of the usual solutions have helped.

This is what I have in SQLServer:

Table:

```
Course_License_Date DATE,
```

Entry:

```
INSERT INTO Certs2 VALUES ('INSERT INTO Certs2 VALUES ('2004-09-20'););
```

This is what I have in my PHP file:

```
<?php echo date('F d, Y', strtotime($row['Course_License_Date'])); ?>
```

This is the result I get:

```
December 31, 1969
```

Retrieving the date looks correct on SQL server (ex: Select * from Certs2). Not sure why its not translating correctly to my php file.

I have also tried this:

```
 <?php  $date = date_create($row["Expiration_Date"]);
             echo date_format($date, 'm/d/Y');
```

But gives me an empty Data.

Note: I am using SQL Server not MySQL

It does not seem to be a quoting problem

Comment: No < ?php is without the space bar.

Comment: Not sure what you are saying here @chris85

Comment: @chris85 I am still getting: December 31, 1969

Comment: Update the question to your new code. Is `$row['Course_License_Date']` the value you are showing as your `insert`?

Comment: @chris85 I am currently doing my insert through SQL Server itself. I am just trying to retrieve the data.

Comment: There is nothing here showing your retrieval. If the variable had the value you think it has it would work. Start debugging there. https://eval.in/668438 (I've updated the question for you)

Comment: Why not use the [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) class? rather than strtotime and date functions?

Comment: Kind of why I'm confused. Everything looks correct. I've been going at this little issue for about 2-3 hours now. It doesnt make any sense

Comment: Hey @chris85 I have found the answer (or a work-around).  Used this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7477943/how-to-retrieve-a-sql-datetime-object-with-a-php-row   Not sure why I had to turn it into a string, but works for my use I suppose. if you enlighten me on why you think this is, would be great.

Comment: Turned it into a string as a work-around. Followed:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7477943/how-to-retrieve-a-sql-datetime-object-with-a-php-row

Comment: That seems to be based on how you are returning the value. What does the function you are using return? That answer looks like it is an object.